# Solving for trivial solutions of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My friend and I came across this problem while looking through some homework.

Say you had a $3 \times 4$ matrix that reduced down to something like this:
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
And you wanted to solve for  the trivial solutions:

$x_1 = -2x_2$

$x_2 = t$

$x_3 = 0$

$x_4 =$ ?

What does $x_4 =$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x_4$ can be arbitrary, say $s$. This is because we have 4 unknowns but just 2 linearly independent equations. Hence we have 2 degrees of freedom to work with. One is used to let $x_2$ be arbitrary, say $t$. $x_1$ follows from $x_2$ and $x_3$ must be 0. The remaining degree of freedom can be used to let $x_4$ be an arbitrary $s$.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. We have another question, what do the free variables represent, you say degrees of freedom, what do you mean by that?

Comment: It means you can choose it to be any number you want. For example, if we let $t = 1, s = 3$, then $(-2, 1, 1, 3)$ is a valid solution. Similarly, if $t=-222, s = 123$, $(444, -222, 1, 123)$ is also a solution. All solutions to the problem then come from assigning values to $s$ and $t$

Comment: Ya, we get that. We mean, geometrically speaking, what do the free variables do for the plane/line created by the linearly independent vectors.

Comment: The vectors associated to each free variable form a basis for the solution space. For the equation, the solution lies in a 2-dimensional space over $\mathbb{R}^4$. The vectors $(-2,1,0,0)$ and $(0,0,0,1)$ associated with $t$ and $s$ forms a basis for the 2-dimensional solution space.

Comment: Okay, so how would I determine what this in in this situation? (dot, line, plane, hyperplane)?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not that well-versed in this language but I'd suppose you could call our answer a plane (since it's 2-dimensional)?